# Elements of orders $2k$, for $k\geq 5$ in a semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a non-solvable group, $N$ be an abelian 2-subgroup of $G$ such that $N=C_G(N)$ and $G/N\cong Sz(8)$. Does $G$ has elements of orders $2k$, for $k\geq 5$?

Comment: It might have! It depends on the action of $G$ on $N$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an irreducible module $M$ of dimension $12$ for $H := {\rm Sz}(8)$ over ${\mathbb F}_2$ in which the elements of order $5$, $7$ an $13$ all act fixed-point-freely. So, if we let $G$ be the semidirect prodcut of $M$ with $H$, then $G$ satisfies your conditions. In fact, the orders of elements of $G$ are $1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 13$.

Alternatively, let $L$ be the direct sum of $M$ and the trivial module for $H$, so ${\rm dim}(L)=13$. Then the semidirect product of $L$ with $H$ has elements of order $10,14$ and $26$.

Comment: Suppose that the action is not given. In general case can we say that $G$ has elements of orders 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,13,14,26? We know that $Sz(8)$ has Frobenius subgroups of orders 10,14,20,52 and therefore $G$ has elements of orders 4 and 8. Also since $Sz(8)$ has classes the order of their representatives are 2,4,5,7 and 13, $G$ has elements of these orders. What can we say about 10, 14 and  26?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you are asking. What do you mean by the "general case". Since there are examples in which there are elements of order $10$ and also examples in which there is no element of order $10$, the re can be no answer that applies in all cases.

Comment: I mean without considering the action of $G$ on $N$, we have $\lbrace 1,2,4,5,7,8,13\rbrace\subseteq \pi_e(G)$. I want to know is there an element of order $2k$ for $k\geq 5$?

Comment: But as I keep saying, the answer depends on the action of $G$ on $N$, so your question is meaningless. What would be your answer to the following question? Let $G$ be a finite group. Without considering the order of $G$, does $G$ have an element of order $2$?